# Mount any USB drive

Tags: usb, mount

I am facing some issues concerning the mounting process of usb drives.
What i want to have in the end is, that i am connecting the usb drive to the pi and pressing a button to start a procedure to copy a folder from the pi to the usb drive. So with the button being pressed i mount the usb drive, then copy the register and umount it afterwards. The thing i would like to achieve is to be able to use any usb drive and not just a specific one. To be precise: i am looking for a command like

> mount /dev/sd* /mnt

so the pi will just mount anything it finds and not just the sda1 as it is doing with the code i am running right now. Below you'll find my code:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo cp -r /home/pi/... /mnt
sudo umount /mnt
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you have already should work if you are only mounting one drive at a time.

Comment: with one drive it does work perfectly. but another one doesnt work at all. with df -h i found out, that the second one was called sdb. thats why i was looking for sd*. or am i wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any particular error?

Comment: okay, i double checked it again. you were right it was obviously just because i had two of them connected at the same time

Comment: I learned something here... Is there any way I could permanently mount one? Like, wire it to the USB internally? Without ugly soldering?

Comment: What do you mean by permanently?  Is connected to a USB port not permanent enough?

Comment: If you have two (or more) USB storage devices attached and mount them with `/dev/sd*` to `/mnt*` (theoretical), what mount point you will take to copy to?